# Tomcat6 UTF-8 Character display Problem

Tags: mysql, jsp, tomcat, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a strange problem with getting extended characters to display in a JSP/Servlet webapp using Struts 2 running on Tomcat 6 with a MySQL database. I have deployed this application to two different servers both connecting to the same database and appearing to have the same setup (samne version of Ubuntu, same version of tomcat, same version of MySQL etc) and on one server (my development one) extended characters display fine, but on the other one (my production server - typical!) they don't display. So I assume there must be some server configuration setting they I haven't got done properly on the production server.

Some things I have checked:

- I have the following lines in all of my `.jsp` pages:

  ```
  <%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="utf-8" contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8" %>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  ```
- The Tomcat `server.xml` files on the production and develompent servers are the same and contain `URIEncoding="UTF-8"`.
- The `web.xml` files on the production and development servers are the same.
- The character sets in the database are set correctly and the correct characters are in there. I can also see them displayed correctly on the dev server which makes me think it's not a database problem.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Add the **URIEncoding="UTF-8"** in connector configuration in server.xml then try.

Comment: Thanks Asad. URIEncoding="UTF-8" is in my server.xml files on both the development and production servers, but it still doesn't seem to work on the production one.

Answer (score 1):

You've covered pretty much everything. The only thing which you haven't covered in your list is the MySQL JDBC connection URL. The MySQL JDBC driver will use the platform default charset to send the data whenever the `characterEncoding` attribute is not specified in the JDBC URL. Apparently your production server platform is not using UTF-8 as default charset. You need to fix the MySQL JDBC connection URL as follows:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Another thing which you haven't covered is the request encoding. This is not necessarily directly related to your problem as you would have seen the same problem on other environments. But you should also have a `Filter` which basically does `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")` whenever it is retrieved as `null`.

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html#Databases) - [Databases](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html#Databases)